# Merging two PHP arrays with same numeric key

Tags: php, arrays, merge, nested

Having some difficulty trying to merge two arrays with the same numeric key. I have tried `array_merge()` and `array_merge_recursive()`, but all that seems to do is append the second array.

The first array has the following form:

```
Array
(
    [384] => Array
        (
            [name] => SomeMovieName1
            [age] => 12.2 hrs
            [IMDBLink] => 
            [IMDBRating] => 
            [coverArt] => 
        )

    [452] => Array
        (
            [name] => SomeMovieName2
            [age] => 13.1 hrs
            [IMDBLink] => 
            [IMDBRating] => 
            [coverArt] => 
        )

    [945] => Array
        (
            [name] => SomeMovieName3
            [age] => 13.6 hrs
            [IMDBLink] => 
            [IMDBRating] => 
            [coverArt] => 
        )
)
```

And here is the second array I want to combine/merge with the first:

```
Array
(
    [384] => Array
        (
            [IMDBRating] => 7.2
            [IMDBLink] => http://www.imdb.com/LinkToMovie1
            [coverArt] => http://www.SomeLinkToCoverArt.com/1
        )

    [452] => Array
        (
            [IMDBRating] => 8.2
            [IMDBLink] => http://www.imdb.com/LinkToMovie2
            [coverArt] => http://www.SomeLinkToCoverArt.com/2
        )

    [945] => Array
        (
            [IMDBRating] => 6.2
            [IMDBLink] => http://www.imdb.com/LinkToMovie3
            [coverArt] => http://www.SomeLinkToCoverArt.com/3
        )
)
```

And after merging, I would like the result to be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => SomeMovieName1
            [age] => 12.2 hrs
            [IMDBRating] => 7.2
            [IMDBLink] => http://www.imdb.com/LinkToMovie1
            [coverArt] => http://www.SomeLinkToCoverArt.com/1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => SomeMovieName2
            [age] => 13.1 hrs
            [IMDBRating] => 8.2
            [IMDBLink] => http://www.imdb.com/LinkToMovie2
            [coverArt] => http://www.SomeLinkToCoverArt.com/2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => SomeMovieName3
            [age] => 13.6 hrs
            [IMDBRating] => 6.2
            [IMDBLink] => http://www.imdb.com/LinkToMovie3
            [coverArt] => http://www.SomeLinkToCoverArt.com/3
        )
)
```

Not sure if it's because of the inner arrays causing an issue that it won't work directly with `array_merge()` or `array_merge_recursive()`. Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: why did the merged array change its $key values from `[384][452][945]` to `[0][1][2]`?

Comment: I'm using an ID field I assign to each key in both arrays so that when I would combine them later I could use the keys to know which IMDB/etc element combined with what later on. I'm sure I could have done it a different way, but this was the first idea in my mind to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code to merge array. Code generates desired output required to you. I have used sample array as given by you:

```
<?php
    $arr1=array(
        "384"=>array("name"=>"SomeMovieName1","age"=>"12.2 hrs","IMDBLink"=>"","IMDBRating"=>"", "coverArt"=>""),
        "452"=>array("name"=>"SomeMovieName2","age"=>"15.2 hrs","IMDBLink"=>"","IMDBRating"=>"", "coverArt"=>""),
        "954"=>array("name"=>"SomeMovieName3","age"=>"4.2 hrs","IMDBLink"=>"","IMDBRating"=>"", "coverArt"=>"")
    );
    $arr2=array(
       "384" => array("IMDBLink" => "7.2", "IMDBRating" => "http://www.imdb.com/LinkToMovie1", "coverArt" => "http://www.SomeLinkToCoverArt.com/1"),
       "452" => array("IMDBLink" => "5","IMDBRating" => "http://www.imdb.com/LinkToMovie2", "coverArt" => "http://www.SomeLinkToCoverArt.com/2"),
       "954"=>array("IMDBLink" => "8","IMDBRating" => "http://www.imdb.com/LinkToMovie3", "coverArt" => "http://www.SomeLinkToCoverArt.com/3")
    );
    $arr3 = array();
    foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val)
    {
         $arr3[] = array_merge($val, $arr2[$key]);
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr3);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect. My gut told me I was probably going to need to loop through one of the arrays with a foreach and use `array_merge()`

Answer (score 3):

`array_merge_recursive` doesn't work because your outer array has numeric keys, not string keys. When `array_merge` or `array_merge_recursive` are given numeric arrays, they append them rather than merging elements with the same keys.

Instead, you can map through the arrays and merge the corresponding elements.

```
$result = array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2);
```

Note that this code assumes that the two input arrays have all the same keys in the same order. If they're not in the same order, you can use `ksort` on them first to rearrange them.

If they can have different keys, though, you need a different solution, like the loop in Webang's answer.

Comment: It might be possible that the two arrays would have different order of keys, but I suppose I could just sort them before using your solution. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to run your arrays in a foreach loop and just insert each value into your initial array. Lets call the first array `$myFirstArray` and the second array `$mySecondArray`:

```
foreach ($myFirstArray as $key => $value)
{
  $myFirstArray[$key][IMDBRating] = $mySecondArray[$key][IMDBRating];
  $myFirstArray[$key][IMDBLink] = $mySecondArray[$key][IMDBLink];
  $myFirstArray[$key][coverArt] = $mySecondArray[$key][coverArt];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this, but it should work:

Call your first array $ar1, and second $ar2

```
$result=array();
foreach($ar1 as $k=>$v)
{
 //if there is a corresponding array2 element
 if( isset($ar2[$k]) ){ 
       $result[] = array( $v['name], $v['age'], $ar2[$k]['IMDBLink'], $ar2[$k]['IMDBRating'],$ar2['coverArt']);
 }
}

//result
print_r($result);
```