# PHP Comparing Key/Value in Multidimensional Array Made from CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I have two(2) .csv files as such:

`CompanySubset.csv`

```
| id | company   | description               |
|----|-----------|---------------------------|
| 1  | Apple     | Description for Apple     |
| 2  | Microsoft | Description for Microsoft |
| 3  | IBM       | Description for IBM       |
```

---

`ContactSubset.csv`

```
| id | name  | address           | phone       |
|----|-------|-------------------|-------------|
| 1  | Bob   | 1234 Address Lane | 1+234567890 |
| 2  | Sally | 4321 Address Lane | 1+987654321 |
| 3  | Cam   | 2468 Address Lane | 1+468135901 |
```

---

Using php, I need to read each file and compare the `id` column for matches between the two(2). If I find a matching id between the two(2), then I need to merge that specific row together.

**Ex:** `CompanySubset` `id` 1 matches `ContactSubset` `id` 1. Therefore, the row with an `id` of 1 on `ContactSubset` will be merged with row 1 on `CompanySubset`. Which will then form the following:

```
| id | company | description           | name | address           | phone       |
|----|---------|-----------------------|------|-------------------|-------------|
| 1  | Apple   | Description for Apple | Bob  | 1234 Address Lane | 1+234567890 |
```

---

I have been able to get each .csv into an array(see below), but thats about it.

```php
$filename = 'CompanySubset.csv';

$company_array = [];

if (($handle = fopen("{$filename}", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($companyData = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $company_array[] = $companyData;
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Why `"{$filename}"` and not just `$filename`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves it by first reading the ContactSubset.csv and creating an array indexed by the first field (removing it from the result using `array_shift()`).

Then the second loop is virtually the same as your code already, but as it reads each line it checks for the contact details and uses `array_merge()` to add in the extra details...

```
$filename = 'ContactSubset.csv';
$contact_array = [];

if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($contactData = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        $id = array_shift($contactData);
        $contact_array[$id] = $contactData;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$filename = 'CompanySubset.csv';
$company_array = [];

if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($companyData = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        if ( isset($contact_array[$companyData[0]]) )   {
            $companyData = array_merge($companyData, $contact_array[$companyData[0]]);
        }
        $company_array[] = $companyData;
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
print_r($company_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `id` element as the keys of the arrays. Then you can merge the related rows.

```
$filename = 'CompanySubset.csv';

$company_array = [];

if ($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) {
    while ($companyData = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) {
        $company_array[$companyData[0]] = array_slice($companyData, 1);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$filename = 'ContactSubset.csv';

$contact_array = [];

if ($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) {
    while ($contactData = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) {
        $contact_array[$companyData[0]] = array_slice($contactData, 1);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

See [Merging two PHP arrays with same numeric key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807532/merging-two-php-arrays-with-same-numeric-key) for methods to merge the array elements with the same keys.

There's also no need for all those `!== FALSE` tests, just use the value of the assignment as the conditional expression (there are a few times when this is needed, e.g. testing the result of `array_search()` because `0` is falsey, but none of your uses require it).

Answer (score 0):

**Following function has been used:**

> **[array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) - Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array**
>
> **[array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) - Merge one or more arrays**

**Solution:**

```
$companySubset = [
  1 => ['Apple','Description for Apple'],
  2 => ['Microsoft','Description for Microsoft'],
  3 => ['IBM','Description for IBM']
];

$contactSubset = [
 1 => ['Bob','1234 Address Lane','1+234567890 '],
 2 => ['Sally','4321 Address Lane','1+987654321'],
 3 => ['Cam','2468 Address Lane','1+468135901']
];
$res =[];
array_walk($companySubset, function($v,$k) use ($contactSubset, &$res){
  $res[] = array_key_exists($k, $contactSubset) ? array_merge($v,$contactSubset[$k]) : $v;
});
```

Comment: This still leaves open the problem of creating the two arrays correctly from the files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two two-dimensional arrays with id's as a keys out of your csv's.
2. Use https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect-key.php to get set of id's that intersect between two.
3. Iterate through set of id's from step 2 if there is any and compare actual values.